# Azure webjobs does not override appsettings.json with Azure Application Settings

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I have a Azure web job (`.NET Core 2.2`) that reads a couple of settings from configuration at startup like this:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .UseEnvironment(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"))
    .ConfigureWebJobs()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
    {
        configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConsole();

        var instrumentationKey = hostingContext.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
        {
            Console.Writeline(instrumentationKey); // <- this always outputs key from appsettings.json, not from Azure Settings
            logging.AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey);
        }
    })
    .UseConsoleLifetime();
```

As you can see, `appsettings.json` file is supposed to have a `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` key, and it's reading it fine in development environment.

Now, for production, I want to override this `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` key, by adding a setting with the same key in Azure Application Settings web interface.

However, when I deploy my webjob to Azure, it still has the old app insights key from `appsettings.json`. In order to force my webjob to have the overridden key from Azure Application settings, I have to delete the app insights key from `appsettings.json`.

Is there a way for my webjob to use Azure Application settings without having to delete keys from `appsettings.json` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that Azure App Settings get sent via environment variables; and, you are loading environment variables first, then overriding with appsettings.json:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
    {
        configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
    })
```

Reverse this to

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
    {
        configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
        configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
```

And it will load your appsettings.json first, then override with environment variables.